# Bug de blur em input

Tags: html, css

porque meu css quando eu adiciono o seguinte trecho de codigo em meu input acontece isso:

```css
#container-header{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #252525;
    position: fixed;
    top:  100%;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

#container-header #container-header-search{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
}

#container-header #container-header-search form input{
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: none;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    width: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="container-header">
        <div id="container-header-search">
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar">
                <button>Ok</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

fica com esse efeito "blur" bem feio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não notei muito blur... vc se refere a espessura da borada das laterais estarem diferentes das bordas superior e inferior?

Comment: sim é isso mesmo, isso não acontece quando eu tiro o "transform"

Comment: se eu adicionar **margin-top: -1px;** o problema some, só que queria muito saber a causa do mesmo.

Comment: O problema é de renderização do browser quando ele ajusta o eixo x/y do elemento. Pra corrigir só no "jeitinho" mesmo, eu ia te sugerir colocar assim    ` transform: translateY(-50%) scaleY(0.98)` , mas isso tb é uma gambiarra...

Comment: já estou acostumado a usar gambiarras kkkk